# Configuring stop times for scheduler

Tags: iccube

Our data source goes under nightly maintenance during which if icCube tries to deploy, a `java.io.IOException: Input/output error` is generated that crashes the icCube process. Crashing and restarting, or creating a cron to restart the process is not ideal as it requires full deploy loads afterwards.

Is it possible to schedule a start / stop time or interval time during which a scheduled refresh should run? For example, if we were to only do scheduled loads / incr loads between 6am - 6pm, this should prevent icCube from crashing.

Alternatively, the crashing can be fixed but the only errors I see are:
`log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,
java.io.IOException: Input/output error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to configure the internal scheduler like that. Nevertheless, for custom scheduling, you can use a cron and external icCube commands related to schema management ([www](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/using/cube_management.php)).

The error does not seem to be related to a missing data source. Please contact icCube directly to troubleshoot that crash.

[edit: this feature will be available from icCube v5]

Comment: The link you referenced describes that examples can be found at XmlaSchemasClientExample. Where can I find this class? Is there an example anywhere how to use Java to trigger schema loads?

Comment: Please contact icCube for a download link.